# ¿Como crear un campo calculado que guarde la cantidad de dias que restan segun la diferencia de fecha?

Tags: mysql-workbench

Estoy trabajando con un Sistema de Rent-a-Car, y necesito saber cuanto tiempo de uso le queda a un Cliente, para esto quiero crear un campo calculado que se genere a partir de la fecha actual(del sistema) y la Fecha_Final.

```
 SELECT DATEDIFF(Fecha_Final,CURDATE()
```

esta consulta me da lo que busco, pero al guardarlo en una columna que se genere automático me da el siguiente error:

> ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select datediff(Fecha_Final,CURDATE())) STORED'

¿Alguna recomendación por favor?

Comment: Nos muestras por favor cómo estás intentando almacenarla?

Comment: Creo un campo llamado Dias_Restantes y marco la casilla **G** que indica que sera Generada, en Default/Expression le pongo DATEDIFF(Fecha_Final,CURDATE()) que es el código que quiero que me genere cada vez que se inserte un registro, y le digo que sea Stored para que se almacene, pero me da el error 1064. ¿Alguna recomendación por favor?